# handling large number of REST calls in java script (3000 and Above rest calls)

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I am working on an application where we are sending 3000 and above REST urls to get data from server. and we have a timeout of 55sec for each request.

in my scenario it is serving some of rest calls and remaining are going to timeout. so no data is coming as a response.

How to handle this to make all rest calls successful.

Comment: limit the number of simultaneous requests "in flight" (most browsers wont do more than 6 per domain if I remember correctly)

Comment: As you have tagged the question with `promise` - this should be very easy to achieve

Comment: even after using promise also it's going for timeout issue

Comment: perhaps your code is wrong. Who can tell, you haven't posted any. Are you making all 3000 requests at once? you need to not do that

Comment: So How to divide that request and send promise. Is their any mechanisam

Comment: yes there is, I already said that it's relatively easy to do in my second comment

Comment: Are these all requests to your own server? If they are, can't you optimize it so the server can accept a number of these requests all bundled into one, and sends back a single reply for all of them?

Comment: its not our own server @Michael Geary